# Java Regex match anything that matches given pattern and is not between a given character

Tags: java, regex

I have a parser that applies regex rules on a given string.
The first match of each rule is removed and placed into a node.

One of the rules tries to find variables, which are in between `|` symbols consisting of only digits, letters, underscore and dash.
The rule that does this is the following: `(?:\|)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(?:\|)+?`

For example we have the expression:  `part1+250+|part2|+part3`
It matches on `|part2|` which is a variable.

Now I need another rule that matches constants, which can consist of only (digits, letters, underscore, dash and spaces).
But it should **not** match on the variables.

Taking a look at the same example expression, it should match the following:
`part1`,`250`,`part3`
It should match anything that is (digit, letter, space, underscore, dash) and is **not** between `|` symbols.

How can I achieve this using a **single** regex expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a single-pattern implementation of your solution:

```
String input = "part1+250+|part2|+part3";

Pattern p = 
//                   | group 1 ("variable")
//                   | | positive look behind for "|"
//                   | |      | character class for allowed characters
//                   | |      |             | quantifier for 1+ instance, greedy
//                   | |      |             | | positive lookahead for "|"
//                   | |      |             | |      | OR
//                   | |      |             | |      || group 2 ("constant") 
//                   | |      |             | |      ||| negative lookbehind for "|"
//                   | |      |             | |      |||       | allowed chars
//                   | |      |             | |      |||       |             | quantifier
//                   | |      |             | |      |||       |             | | negative
//                   | |      |             | |      |||       |             | | lookahead
//                   | |      |             | |      |||       |             | | 
    Pattern.compile("((?<=\\|)[ a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(?=\\|))|((?<!\\|)[ a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(?!\\|))");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.printf("Variable: %s%nConstant: %s%n", m.group(1), m.group(2));
}
```

**Output**

```
Variable: null
Constant: part1
Variable: null
Constant: 250
Variable: part2
Constant: null
Variable: null
Constant: part3
```

**Notes**

- Here it prints everything, but you can of course check for `null`s and infer whether a "variable", a "constant", or nothing's been found.
- Quick solution here, so there might be edge cases not covered.
- Grouping here is Java 6 styled for backwards compatibility. Java 7's named groups are a lot more fun though!

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] split = s.replaceAll("\\|\\w+\\|", "").replaceAll("\\W+", "-").split("-");
```

This will contain all your needs